# Latex pdf output does not show miter line joins drawn in Ipe editor

Tags: graphics, eps, epstool, ipe

I am using Ipe to draw eps figures to include in my latex document. I use dvipdfm as the package.

I just discovered a nice feature in Ipe to make line joints sharp by choosing "Line join = miter". However, when the eps figure is included in my Latex document and I zoom in on the output pdf, I still see the normal soft corners.

Does anyone know if/how this is fixable without resorting to completely changing how I do my images such as switching to pdflatex? Perhaps I could do something in Ipe or use a Latex package or an option for dvipdfm?

Comment: We will need to see a demo `.eps` file to have any chance of tackling this!

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from the Ipe developer:

> There was a bug in Ipe 7.0.10 [latest available Windows version] so
>   that the line join was not correctly saved in Postscript output (PDF
>   output was correct). The solution would be to save as PDF and then use
>   pdftoeps or so to convert the figure to Postscript (if you really need
>   to use normal Latex).